# login loop problem after installing nvidia graphics driver

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, nvidia, login, blacklist

i have tried adding nouveau blacklisting problem and I also tried it in ubuntu 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 but nothing worked for me. 
but whenever I install the nvidia driver and restart, it gets into login loop.

Comment: It is solved now, you just have to disable the secure boot

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Crtl + Alt + F2, then login and run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia.*
```

Then re-boot.

Comment: but i need nvidia graphics driver to support cuda as i am using my laptop to train deep learning models using gpu

Comment: If you do as I suggest you will be using the open source nouveau driver, which as far as I know doesn't support cuda. You never mentioned cuda in your OP.

Comment: i have gtx1060 nvidia graphic card which supports cuda as mentioned in their website

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm if the drivers install are the correct one for you video card.

first solution:

sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx <--- go to the website and see what card you are using.

Second solution

sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME